# How much of a Devil Fruit must be consumed to gain the power?

Tags: one-piece

To get the devil fruit power is it necessary to eat the whole devil fruit? What if one person eats half and some other person eats the rest? Will both of them get the devil fruit power?

I am currently on the Dressrosa Arc. So, please try to give a spoiler-free answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not necessary to eat the entire fruit. A single bite is enough for the consumer to obtain the power. Oda addressed this in Volume 77's SBS corner.

Source: https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_77

During the CP9 arc, Jabra also states that "one bite will leave you with a lifetime of problems", when warning Kalifa and Kaku about Devil Fruits.

If two people split the fruit and share it, the person who takes the first bite will obtain the power. This was illustrated with Ace's story on how he got the Flame-Flame Fruit.

Answer (score 2):

No, its not necessary to eat all the fruit, if you eat just a piece you're gonna acquire its power.

And for the later question, the first who eat from the devil fruit acquire its power, so its pointless to share it with other if you have already eaten from it

proof : SBS 48 & 77

https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_48

https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_77

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references. I'm also curious about this and that SBS is the only proof you have to validate your claim. Otherwise, your answer might be removed by mods or flagged by other users.

Comment: You can find the proof on SBS 48 & 77

Comment: Including the actual SBS information and the link instead of just mentioning it would be preferable so if in case the link would go down, the information is still visible to viewers of this answer.